# javascript for stopped working

Tags: javascript, wordpress

This is how script appeared in Wordpress visual editor and database. Has been working fine until this pm.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
  if ( xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
       document.getElementById("droptargethere").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       var svg = document.getElementById("droptargethere").childNodes;
       for(var i = 0; i < svg.length; i++) {
         var element = svg[i];
         if (element.localName == "div") {
           var rect = element.offsetTop;
           var retID = element.id;
           updTable (retID , rect , "../wp-admin/custom/");
         }
       }
     }
```

but viewing source in browser looks like this, essentially corrupted. After the for statement it is one continuous line.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
  if ( xmlhttp.status==200)
     {
       document.getElementById("droptargethere").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
       var svg = document.getElementById("droptargethere").childNodes;
       for(var i = 0; i < svg.length; i++) {               var element = svg[i];               if (element.localName == "div") {                 var rect = element.offsetTop;                 var retID = element.id;                 updTable (retID , rect , "../wp-admin/custom/");               }             }           }
```

Further investigation showed it was the following line that seems to cause the issue

```
for(var i = 0; i < svg.length; i++)
```

Tried re-keying, `while`.., `do...while` but makes no difference.

Also appears not to like "if" statements. Frustrating

Anyone got any ideas, due to demonstrate to client in morning and I cannot see a way round it.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the console?

Comment: ...visual editor? You can't put JS in the visual editor

Comment: That the code is on one line should not break anything since you have the necessary semicolons to allow this

Comment: so does the code just look ugly and it work or does it look ugly and not work in the browser? If it doesn't work are you getting any errors?

Comment: What is it supposed to be doing?

Comment: Have you checked the contents of `document.getElementById("droptargethere")`?

Comment: svg.length is almost certainly 0. Use a debugger and see. The fact that it is on one line is fine.

Comment: Hi been using debugger all the time. Despite having semi colons it fails to execute and complete. The net result is that other functions are showing as undefined. Just had similar issue with "if" statement. Could one my .js files be corrupt? How would I know? How would I fix?